# What is an alternative way to verify my domain on firebase

Tags: dns, verification

I am trying to verify my domain on firebase.com.

Here I have two txt records. My domain provider supports only one entry.

I found on one help site from google the entry that my provider "strato.de" does not support the verification from firebase and that I can try an alternative domain verfication. Then I was linked to stackoverflow.

What is the alternative way to verify my domain on firebase.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. So if anybody has a solution, hmu.

Answer (score -5):

I have contacted the support of firebase.com.

After a few days I received an email with an alternative way to verify the domain.

I did not try out the alternative way, becuase I found another solution for my problem.

Comment: Could you describe the solution? This answer isn't very helpful as it is.

Comment: After getting help from firebase support the link works now.